# How to accommodate GroupBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a "GroupBox" which to maximize the window I subrepone to others "GroupBox"

No way to fix it. Anyone?
[image: Form]

This is the XAML. This is the xml do not know if there is way to add some definition to fix, any label or something.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Laboratorio.Calibracion"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="490" d:DesignWidth="660">
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Calibracion" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="Equipo">
                <Grid>
                    <Label x:Name="serialLbl" Content="Serial:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="serialTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="85,10,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="descripcionTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" Margin="209,10,0,0" IsEnabled="False"/>
                    <Label x:Name="resolucionLbl" Content="Resolucion:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,41,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="resolucionTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="85,41,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Header="Patron">
                <Grid>
                    <Label x:Name="patronLbl" Content="Patron:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="106,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="patronLbl_Copy" Content="Niv. Referencia:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,80,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="resolucionTxb_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="106,80,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="patronLbl_Copy1" Content="Fluido:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,41,0,0"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="106,41,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Header="Condificones">
                <Grid>
                    <Label x:Name="temperaturaLbl" Content="Temperatura:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="temperaturaTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Margin="94,10,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="humedadLbl" Content="Humedad:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="135,10,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="humedadTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Margin="205,10,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Header="Comprobacion Inicial">
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="compInicialDgv">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Presion Patron"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lecturas"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Error"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Header="Segunda Secuencia">
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="segSecDgv">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Presion Patron"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lecturas"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Error"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: If you've changed your XAML for your edit, it would be good to see what you have now.

Comment: ok, I'll add the new XAML

Comment: @ChrisFannin I just updated the code in the publication

Comment: You still have Margin on the Condificones groupbox. You also have them on the sub elements, but strip the margin on that groupbox and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @ChrisFannin , I've updated the code apparently improved but still remains blank when the window is bigger, lacking any property?

Comment: You'll need to adjust the various layout and sizing properties as I mentioned. For your columns, you can try setting the width to `*`. Add other attributes as you see fit. As Chris W mentioned, you may also want to look up some WPF/XAML fundamentals, particularly around layout. It sounds like he is going to rework your entire XAML for you, so you'll be able to see the results. I would, but I'm at work, so I don't have the time. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using hardcoded size attributes (`Margin`, `Width`, `Height`, etc). I assume you designed it with drag-and-drop from the toolbox. You can get strange results when resizing the form with such hardcoded values.

I would recommend you change all of them to get rid of the hardcoded margins, edit the parent `Grid` to use `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` with appropriate sizing information (absolutes, Auto, *), set the `Grid.Row` `Grid.Column` `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan` properties of the `GroupBox` controls, and then tweak the various sizing details (`Margin`, `Padding`, `MinWidth`, `MinHeight`, etc) as needed.

Do the same thing for any child `Grid` elements. You may also want to use other container elements.

Here is a slimmed-down example of what I'm talking about.

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Calibracion" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" /> <!-- Or '*', 'Auto', etc -->
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" /> <!-- Or '*', 'Auto', etc -->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Header="Equipo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <!-- GroupBox contents here -->
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Patron" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <!-- GroupBox contents here -->
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Condificones" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                <!-- GroupBox contents here -->
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I think I did not understand, I must eliminate the "margin" property of the GroupBox and add? remove them and overlap all the time

Comment: Your Margins are explicitly setting positions. Instead of doing that, you can edit your `Grid` to contain Rows and Columns. In your screenshot, it looks like you have 2 columns and 2 rows. So, just create the definitions for them. Your GroupBoxes look like they could use `Grid` definitions as well and/or possibly `StackPanel`. After doing this, position your controls within it using the previously mentioned attributes. Then they will all autosize correctly without colliding.

Comment: Also, to make spacing around each groupbox within the individual cells, you can manually set the margin to a simple number like `Margin="3"`

Comment: ah ok, so now let it so `<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`

Comment: @Cristian Something like that, yeah. I edited my answer to give a quick example. Make sure you also alter the individual GroupBox contents to take advantage of such definitions and `StackPanel` if needed.

Comment: and add them to this groupbox `<GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="Equipo" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">` effectively they not overlap, but now when I minimize not move. It is normal to make that change feels slower to enter the menu or I did something wrong?

Comment: Sorry amigo but Width="50%" is not valid, they would both just be `Width="*"` for proportional, for percentages would be like 1*, 2*, 3* etc. Also all those Margin, Alignment, Heights, Widths etc aren't necessary on a per instance declaration for your positioning and generally would do you no favors if it's intended to be actually responsive.

Comment: @ChrisW. It was psuedo-coded while on the phone. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hello, I think I still do not understand, I edited my "row" creating 2 rows and 2 columns. But still it does not look good, no longer overlap but there is a very large space. Add a new image in question to show how it looks now

Comment: @Cristian You're likely going to be using `Grid` a lot in your projects. You may want to visit some WPF fundamentals tutorials for XAML to learn how it works a bit better. @ChrisFannin is just trying to show you how to make what you have currently work for your current situation. He's correct in the execution side with that one typo fixed. If you're still struggling, no worries, we've all been there. I'll just re-write your layout for an example in a bit since there isn't much to it. I'll be making tutorials/videos for this sort of thing in the coming months as well as free time allows.